# sort NSMutableArray of Dictionary in swift by a key value

Tags: ios, sorting, swift, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` than contains dictionary of string like this

```
[[link: myurl, title:My title, pubDate: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 07:00:00 PDT], 
[link: my link, title: my title2 , pubDate: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 01:00:00 PDT]]
```

I need to sort this array on `pubDate` key so the Latest event should come on top.
Is there any smart way to do it in swift.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not the the same question - `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are sorted differently. `.sort` is not available on `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should convert your `pubDate` to `NSDate` then compare 2 `dateValue` , It is better than compare 2 `stringValue`.
 Try this code :

```
var itemArray : NSMutableArray = [["link":"myurl", "title":"My title", "pubDate": "Wed, 11 Mar 2015 07:00:00 PDT" ], ["link" : "my link", "title": "my title2" , "pubDate": "Fri, 20 Mar 2015 01:00:00 PDT"]]
let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
itemArray.sortUsingComparator{
    (obj1:AnyObject!, obj2:AnyObject!) -> NSComparisonResult in
    var dateStr1 = obj1["pubDate"] as NSString
    var date1: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr1)!
    var dateStr2 = obj2["pubDate"] as NSString
    var date2: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr2)!
    return date2.compare(date1)
}
```

Result :
[image: ![enter image description here]]

See [Format String for the iPhone NSDateFormatter](https://tahabebek.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/) to get more about dateFormatter